# Abrir ventana topLevel en tkinter

Tags: tkinter

no se cómo explicarlo, pero tengo un problema, que al abrir una ventana topLevel, está ventana se me abre en el monitor 1, y yo la app principal siempre la tengo, en el monitor 2, hay algúna manera de corregir eso?, K se abriera la ventana topLevel donde esté la ventana de la app, ya sea en el monitor 1 o monitor 2.

Comment: Esto es de StackOverflow en ingles, pero responde tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754349/is-there-any-possibility-to-spawn-new-window-in-tkinter-on-the-same-screen-as-hi

Comment: Gracias Dante, lo reviso

Comment: Si lo mire, junto con la respuesta de Dante pude conseguir centrar la ventana y además que se abra en la posición de la ventana padre .. gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Centrar aplicación en medio de la pantalla al abrirla :**

Aquí tienes una posible solución a tu problema

```
window_width,window_height=710,555
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height= root.winfo_screenheight()
position_top = int(screen_height/2 - window_height/2)
position_right = int(screen_width/2 - window_width/2)
root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{position_right}+{position_top}')
```

`window_width,window_height=710,555 --> Asignas las dimensiones ancho/alto.`

El resto del código son operaciones aritméticas para centrar la aplicación al centro de la pantalla.

También, en caso de que quisieras que no se redimensionara tu aplicación utiliza `root.resizable(0,0)`

Un saludo!

Comment: Cualquier duda o información que necesites escribe un comentario !

Comment: Alexci muchas gracias, lo. Probaré

Comment: Me funcionó ☺️ Gracias